# jQuery - eq() seems to refer to a different element than index() - What gives? :/

Tags: jquery, select, indexing

Here's my code: **UPDATED JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
   var cookieName = 'activeMenus';
   var openMenus  = (jQuery.cookie(cookieName) == null) ? 0 : jQuery.cookie(cookieName).substring(1).split(',');
   var wookie     = '';

   jQuery('ul.menu li ul').css('display', 'none');

   // Reopen all the menus from the cookie
   if (openMenus != 0)
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < openMenus.length; i++)
      {
         alert('Opening: ' + openMenus[i]);
         jQuery('ul.menu li').children('ul').eq(openMenus[i]).css('display', 'block');
      }
   }

   // Hide the menu upon click and modify the cookie
   jQuery('ul.menu span.topdaddy span').click(function()
   {
      // Toggle the menu for the clicked link
      jQuery(this).parents('li').find('ul').slideToggle('slow', function()
      {
         // Once the menu has been toggled - Find all the open menus
         jQuery('ul.menu li').children('ul:visible').each(function()
         {
            wookie += ',' + jQuery(this).index(); // Build the index list
            jQuery.cookie(cookieName, wookie);
         });
      });

      wookie = '';
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="item1">
      <a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
   </li>

   <li class="parent item55">
      <span class="topdaddy"><span>Link 2</span></span>

      <ul>
         <li class="item62">
            <a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a>
         </li>

         <li class="item63">
            <a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li class="parent item56">
      <span class="topdaddy"><span>Link 5</span></span>

      <ul>
         <li class="item69">
            <a href="#"><span>Link 6</span></a>
         </li>

         <li class="parent item70">
            <ul>
               <li>asdasd</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li
</ul>
```

It's a menu system that uses cookies to remembers the currently opened menus to reopen those menus each page load.

The code works... But it's a little buggy.

The .eq() call is opening index 2 rather than 1. They're both supposed to be 0-based indexes, so I see no reason why it should be doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I added `>` where it was needed. Also, the index() number we were grabbing took into account the first `li` under `ul.menu` that doesn't have `.parent` class. That's fine, but I just had to make sure that we setting the index on the full set of `li` under `ul.menu`, not limiting the collection to `li.parent`

Let me know how this works for you.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

           var cookieName = 'activeMenus';
           var openMenus  = (jQuery.cookie(cookieName) == null) ? 0 : jQuery.cookie(cookieName).substring(1).split(',');
           var wookie     = '';

           jQuery('ul.menu > li.parent > ul').css('display', 'none');

           if (openMenus != 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < openMenus.length; i++) {
                 alert('Opening: ' + openMenus[i]);
                jQuery('ul.menu > li').eq(openMenus[i]).children('ul').css('display', 'block');
              }
           }
           jQuery('ul.menu span.topdaddy').click(function() {
              jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
                 jQuery('ul.menu > li.parent > ul:visible').each(function() {
                    wookie += ',' + jQuery(this).parent().index(); 
                    jQuery.cookie(cookieName, wookie);
                 });
              });
              wookie = '';
          });
    });
```

---

This code:

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').children('ul:visible').each(function()
     {
        wookie += ',' + jQuery(this).parent().index(); // Build the index list
        jQuery.cookie(cookieName, wookie);
     });
```

...seems to be getting the index of a `li` element that is a child of `ul.menu`.

While this code:

```
     jQuery('ul.menu li ul').eq(openMenus[i]).css('display', 'block');
```

...seems to be using the index from above, but on a different set of elements (the `ul` that is a child of the index you stored in the cookie).

So it looks like you're taking the index of a `ul.menu li` and using it on a `ul.menu li ul`.

Comment: The first code block should be getting the index of the first child UL's of each `ul.menu li`, no? How would I match up those two code blocks to reference the same UL? :/

Comment: It would be, except that this line `wookie += ',' + jQuery(this).parent().index();` is grabbing  the index of the **parent** of the visible `ul` (which is the `li`). Get rid of `parent()`, and you will be getting the index of the `ul` itself.

Comment: Wasn't expecting a reply that quick... Cheers :> I removed parent() so it's just pulling jQuery(this).index() but it's still opening the wrong menu item.

Comment: It seems removing parent() is causing index() to return '1' :/

Comment: Please edit your question with a portion of your HTML. Also update any changes you've made to js. I'm trying to figure out what's going on in your code, but I'm not quite getting it.

Comment: Just to keep you updated, I think I see the problem. The ul.menu structure goes as deep as `ul.menu li ul li ul`. What I'm trying to do is open `ul.menu li ul`. The block of code that gets the index and saves it in the cookie works perfectly. The block of code that opens the menu based on the index is what's flawed. I've noticed that it's opening up `ul.menu li ul li ul`. It's going too deep. I'm guessing this is causing the index problem.

Comment: Direct descendant child selectors to the rescue! ul.menu > li > ul

Comment: Yeah, if it goes deeper than the code you posted, that could be an issue. In terms of `index()` returning '1', that's because the element is at index 1. `index()` returns its position relative to its siblings. The element `span.topdaddy` is at index 0.

Comment: Made a bunch of edits to my answer. Things can be simplified quite a bit. I think I've provided a start.

Comment: The reason for me using `jQuery('ul.menu li').children('ul:visible').each(function()` is that it stops me from having to remove indexes from the 'wookie' when menus get closed. When each menu is clicked it does a quick look to see what menus are open and regenerates the wookie. My code to open the menus is now `jQuery('ul.menu li').eq(openMenus[i]).find('ul').css('display', 'block');` which seems to work. The problem I'm having is finding which menus are open. It, now seems to go deeper than I want. I'm playing around with `jQuery('ul.menu > li > ul:visible').each(function()` which is failing.

Comment: It's still not working >.< A few things 1) I messed up my HTML a little which is now fixed in my original post. There's an extra `ul li` combination. 2) The `>` selector doesn't seem to be working as it should. `jQuery('ul.menu li.parent > ul').css('display', 'none');` is causing all UL's to be set to `display: none` instead of just the first child. 3) What's currently happening when I run the code is my alert() is firing off 17 alerts counting between 0 and 4 for the specific LI I click.

Comment: Yeah, now that you have nested elements with li.parent, you'll need: `jQuery('ul.menu > li.parent > ul').css('display', 'none');` Notice the extra `>`. This will limit it to immediate children of `ul.menu`. Do the same inside the click() event. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Give it a try. Also (somewhat off topic), I noticed that you seem to have a unique class for each `li`. That's fine, but if those are unique, it would seem that you would want those to be IDs instead of classes. Just a thought.